# How can i sum the values of checkboxes in python if they were made using a loop?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, checkbox

Recently i have made a code which adds checkbuttons based on the items i put in the list.Items in the list consist of String connected to integer, so one window with checkboxes would look like this: London(3.40) New York(2.20) California(1.2) etc.What i would like to do now is make a button that when clicked sums the integers from the checkboxes.
Note: I have two lists, one list is list of integers `Example = [1.2,3.4,2.45,2.4]` and other list is list of items `Items = ["London","New York","California","Toronto"]`, after they have been connected with a loop in another list which consists of Items(Value) i made a loop that generates checkbuttons based on amount of Items from that connected list.

I do not know how to implement get() function in a loop so that when i click few checkboxes it sums them and prints them through the button Sum.
In which ways can this be done?

Example of a code:

```
Values = [1.2,3.4,5.4]
Items = ["London","Lisbon","Athens"]

Connect = ['%.2f', % i for i in Values]

while i != len(Connect):
    Items[i] = Items[i]+"(" + Connect[i] + ")"
    i = i+ 1

for j in range(len(Values)):
    items = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text=Items[j], onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```

From now on i need to make a function that will sum checked checkboxes and print the sum once button Sum is clicked.
Thank you for your help in forward!

Comment: Please use `for` loops instead of `while` loops. `while` loops are harder to understand. Also look at a few python tutorials.

Comment: Noted, i tried researching but i couldn't find how to make it sum values once checkboxes are checked because it generates infinite number of checkboxes depending on list i manually write.

Comment: Do you have tkinter variables attached to the `Checkbutton`s? Like `IntVar`?

Comment: Yes i do, i think you helped me today with the other question based on cancel button.

Comment: ```def sum() :
   for i in Values :``` Basically i get stuck here, so now what i want to do is check if the checkbox from index i is selected and sum the value of it through Values[i] but i do not understand how?Then i want to put this as a command in button i made.

Comment: Can you please try my answer now? I fixed the stupid mistake that I made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store the checkbuttons or the associated variables in a loop. You can then iterate over the loop to get the values.

Since you are wanting to created checkbuttons that represent numbers other than 1 or 0, I recommend you set the value of the checkbutton to the actual value rather than 1.

For example, you can create the checkbuttons like so:

```
vars = []
for label, value in zip(Items, Values):
    var = tk.DoubleVar(value=0)
    vars.append(var)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=label, onvalue=value, offvalue=0, variable=var)
    cb.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
```

With the variables in `vars`, we can sum them by getting the value of each variable and then adding them together:

```
def do_sum():
    values = [var.get() for var in vars]
    result = sum(values)
    print("sum:", result)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to sum the corresponding `Values` with the checkbuttons that are checked.

Comment: @TheLizzard: that's what this code does. `values` is a list of the values of each variable` and `sum` adds them together. I'm not sure what you mean. My example just sets the value to 1 for each checkbutton, but if each checkbutton had a different value it would still work.

Comment: I already made the buttons, i tried adding vars.append(var) but it does not recognize append function for some reason

Comment: @CupidONO: if it doesn't recognize `append`, then `vars` must not be a list.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think OP is trying to do something like `sum(var.get() * value for var, value in zip(vars, Values))` - taken from Reti43's comment on my answer. You might want to change the `onvalue` when creating the checkbutton

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, I see now what you were trying to say. I've updated my example to show how you can set the checkbuttons to each of the values in `Values`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Now your answer does the same as mine but in a more elegant way and is much faster :D.

Comment: I apologize for not responding, currently i am checking if Sir Lizzards code will work, i sincerely appreciate your help and i am going to get back to it in a minute.Thank you again for the help and time you provided.

Comment: @CupidONO This answer is better than mine (in terms of running speed and elegancy) so I will delete my answer.

Comment: Your answer also works i just realized my print was in for loop.